# Javascript - Math.random as parameter

Tags: javascript, random

I asked this before, but a little vague and poorly worded.

I have a object that takes in `Action`s and puts them into a stack that it goes through over time. It performs the first `Action` in the stack until it's done, then it performs the second, and so on. There is a `RepeatAction` that can take in an array of other `Action`s and perform them a number of times in a similar fashion. (`.repeat()` simply puts a new `RepeatAction` into the objects stack.

Take this for example:

`object.repeat(10,[new LogAction(Math.random())]);`

Given that `LogAction` only takes in a parameter and logs it out. When the object's repeat function gets called it will put 10 `LogAction`s into its stack, but they will all log the same number. What I'm looking for is a way that it will log a different number all 10 times.

You may say just pass in Math.random as a function, but then what if I want to pass in `4 * Math.random()`?

Any help?

Comment: You could define some kind of chaining thing on `Action`s and build ones for basic operators, e.g. `new LogAction(times(4).of(new Action(Math.random)))`. Or maybe not; I’m still not sure what an `Action` is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needs to *invoke a function (later)* to get a different value. e.g.

```
// pass in the `random` function - do not get a random number immediately!
object.repeat(10, [new LogAction(Math.random)])

// create and pass in a custom function that uses `random` itself
var rand4 = function () { return Math.random() * 4 }
object.repeat(10, [new LogAction(rand4)])
```

Since "LogAction" is not disclosed, I'll make a simple example to work with the above.

```
function LogAction (arg) {
    this.execute = function () {
        // If the supplied argument was a function, evaluate it
        // to get the value to log. Otherwise, log what was supplied.
        var value = (typeof arg === 'function') ? arg() : arg;
        console.log(value);                
    }
}
```

Reading through [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1) will likely increase the appreciation of functions as first-class values, which the above relies upon.

Answer (score 2):

> You may say just pass in Math.random as a function,

Yes, I would.

> but then what if I want to pass in 4 * Math.random()?

Then in place of `Math.random`, use

```
function() { return 4 * Math.random(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass function which returns result of random:

```
object.repeat(10,[new LogAction(function(){return Math.random();})]);
```

And in LogAction function you simply need to check if argument is a function:

```
function LogAction(arg){
    var value = arg&& getType.toString.call(arg) === '[object Function]' ? arg() : arg;

    //log value    
}
```